# How can I get region collapsing/expanding with #region / #endregion for TypeScript in Visual Studio CE 2019?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

We have been using "region collapsing" in TypeScript for some time now, like so:

```
//#region GUI handlers
...some code related to handling GUI events...
//#endregion
```

and this has been working fine in VS2015 CE and VS2017 CE (a little "-" or "+" appears in the left gutter of the code window, which you can use to collapse/expand the block of code, as in C#).

I recently switched to VS2019 CE and this functionality is no longer working.
I've tried installing the "Web Essentials 2019" extension, but that didn't help. I also have the "Editor Enhancements" extension installed right now, but that doesn't work either...

Does someone know how to enable this in VS2019 CE?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JavaScript Regions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.JavaScriptRegions&ssr=false#overview) extension adds support for region comments in JavaScript and TypeScript files.

It doesn't officially support VS 2019, but Daryl LaBar offers his build to work for 2019 here:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z35I5mpI7-cHK6NggTWmwQZtltovKxOP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick indeed! Hopefully the official JavaScript Regions extension gets updated for 2019.

Comment: Link is dead :(

Comment: you are correct. Firewall at work stops links to google drive. My bad.

Comment: As the November 2020 comment states at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.JavaScriptRegions&ssr=false#qna this is natively supported in VS2019 at this point.  But what I can't find is support for a key combo that collapses the javascript/typescript regions.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, short cut: *CTRL + M + L*